# Convert a C style long to a Python style integer

Tags: python

I am using VS2015 with Python 3.5. I have a structure supplied by a C program. The structure has c_ulongs. I want to convert those C style longs to Python integers.

My C data looks like this:

```
class _C_vendrRecord(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1         # pack the struct
    _fields_ = [
    ("currentBalance",             c_ulong * (1)),
    ]
C_vendrRecord = _C_vendrRecord() # used to reference the C formatted data
```

I want to say something like this:

```
currentBalance = C_vendrRecord.currentBalance
```

I've done a fare amount of searching but nothing works. My tries look like these:

```
currentBalance = C_vendrRecord.currentBalance
print(currentBalance)
<vendr.c_ulong_Array_1 object at 0x016AD710>

currentBalance = C_vendrRecord.currentBalance.value
print(currentBalance)
AttributeError: 'c_ulong_Array_1' object has no attribute 'value'
```

And, since I saw a post on a similar issue, I tried this:

```
currentBalance = ctypes.c_long(1).value # in the post
print(currentBalance)
1

currentBalance = ctypes.c_long(C_vendrRecord.currentBalance).value
print(currentBalance)
TypeError was unhandled by user code
Message: an integer is required (got type c_ulong_Array_1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you have specified a one element array but have accessed it as if it is a scalar. Just add [0] to it, e.g. `currentBalance = C_vendrRecord.currentBalance[0]` and it will work.